# To print bunch of 3 lines from notepad

Tags: java

I have a situation where my program needs to read and print bunch of 3 lines at a time. I know basic Java hence finding difficult to write.

I have a text file which has 3 lines of one message; the catch is it’s not only one message but multiple message of three lines. Each time I want to read and print  first message which has 3 lines and then jumpy to 4th line to read next three lines and print them and so on

For example :

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
Test6
Test7
Test8
Test9
```

Now out come should be

```
Test1
Test2
Test3 

Test4
Test5
Test6

Test7
Test8
Test9
```

Need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you just asking how to write a newline character to a text file in Java?

Comment: No David … for example I have one message which has three lines in a note pad then I want to read and print them … then Jump to 4th line and print 4th,5th and 6th and so on because I have messages which has three lines. To clear your confusion my message length is more than one line limit of notepad hence it goes upto third line hence want to print three lines at once and so on

Comment: You can use `System.out.print` to print a `String` without a newline.

Comment: Ummm it’s not only one string of three lines …multiple lines. I have code to print first three lines of text file but I am confused how to read next three lines and so on. 
 
My problem statement is to read every three lines starting from first line. Output should be first three lines and then next three lines so on

Comment: *I have code to print first three lines of text file* please post that code

Comment: I think my problem statement is misleading somehow.. in other words I would like print first three line of text file as one message at a time and then next three lines and so on.

Comment: You need a loop.  Each time you read a line of input, you use `System.out.print( ... )` to copy it to the output.  Then if you've printed three lines in this way, you use `System.out.println()` to print the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to iterate over the lines in file and print them in 'groups' of three lines each. If that is correct - here is a small piece of code that can help you achieve it:

```java
    try {
        File file = new File("<<enter your file path here>>");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        int counter = 0; // Counter to track the number of lines printed

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            
            if(counter < 3) { // Grouping by three lines
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print(line + " "); // Printing on the same line
                counter++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(" "); // Printing a 'newLine' 
                counter = 0; // Reset the counter
            }
        }
        scanner.close(); // Close the scanner

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Change this as per your need 
    }
```

Comment: Just make sure to close() the scanner when you're done ;)

Comment: We have not yet seen the OP's code. Yours should be removed until we do

Comment: Thank you Vini for your Answer …. Thank you others as well